# Where is enp4s0 configured?

Tags: networking

In Debian Jessie, a typical `/etc/network/interfaces` contains a line that looks like this:

```
auto eth0
    allow-hotplug eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

This causes `eth0` to be configured when `ifup -a` is invoked and allows DHCP to assign an IP address. However, when I open up `/etc/network/interfaces` in Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial), I observe that no such directives are present:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

What happened to `eth0` (or its Ubuntu equivalent `enp4s0`)? I have Xen installed, if that makes any difference.

Comment: You can configure `enp4s0` the same way if you like. By default it is configured by NM.

Answer (score 1):

The interface just has another name, a so-called [Predictable Interface Name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134483/why-my-ethernet-interface-is-called-enp0s10-instead-of-eth0), probably assigned after a kernel upgrade. You can work with the NIC exactly as if it was called `eth[N]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior when you are using an Ubuntu flavor with a desktop environment, because all the flavors (except ubuntu server) are using the gnome network manager to handle connections. You can still edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file as shown here: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html (run `ifconfig` to see the connection name, because they are named different now) but then any changes you do at one connection with the gnome network manager will be ignored, so it's better use the `Network Connections` app (click on network applet on the panel and choose `Edit Connections`).

Comment: Yes, but network manager doesn't provide a way to create and manage bridged networks, does it?

Comment: I'm not sure because I've never done it. Is this http://ask.xmodulo.com/configure-linux-bridge-network-manager-ubuntu.html what are you asking?